# Cannot get .click(function() to work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Some of my homework requires me to translate all my javascript code to as much jQuery as possible. I am seeming to have serious issues with this. The main thing I was having problems with, one of many, was the .click function. Here is my code. I cut out the entire program to get just this part to work then move on. If you want to see the full code, let me know.

```
(document).ready(function() {

  $("start_test").click (function() {
      alert("asdf");
  });       

});
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html<
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Clicker</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="click.js"></script>   

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" id="start_test" value="Start Test" />
    <br><br>

    <section id="buttonArray">
        <input type="button" value="        " />
        <input type="button" value="        " />
        <input type="button" value="        " />
        <input type="button" value="        " />
        <input type="button" value="        " />
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="        " />
        <input type="button" value="        " />
        <input type="button" value="        " />
        <input type="button" value="        " />
        <input type="button" value="        " />
    </section>

    <h3>Time remaining: <span id="counter">10</span></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried all different combinations to get the button to work and the only was I was able to get it to work was to use $("input").click but then all the buttons did the action. What am I missing?

Comment: Learn about jQuery/CSS selectors.  You want an ID selector.

Comment: There is no element `start_test`. `$("start_test")` needs a `#`

Comment: `(document).ready(function() {` is something accidentally missing at the start of that line?

Comment: Write #start_test instead of start_test to attch it to the click handler

Comment: `start_test` is an id. It needs to start with a `#` in the query.

Comment: j08691 yes looks like the '$' got cut out.

Comment: I didn't tell you the `$` got cut, Kevin B did. I showed you the `#` was missing.

Comment: @Daniel no need to be rude, OP did the initial legwork and reduced the code to a core problem. It's a beginner question but they took the time to make a good question, even if it's not a good SO question.

Comment: I must have not been able to get the syntax right until now. I just added that and it worked. Goodness. I have been stuck on this too long. Must have been misreading the Murach books, thinking '#' is for the elements, not just by id.

Comment: All of the other .click SO questions had to do with .on, .live, .css issues. Thanks though. Delete as you see fit.

Comment: @TankorSmash - I did not mean to be rude, but meant what I said. If OP does not understand his material in his homework, then that is a learning opportunity and he/she should return to his teacher. That's not rude in my opinion, but common sense with the best intentions.

Comment: @RetroRehab No worries, often times even if a question's title is different the answer is the same. In the duplicate question the answer ends up being 'make sure your selector is accurate', which was the case here.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `$("#start_test")` instead of `$("start_test")` because you're targeting an element with ID and IDs are marked with `#`

Comment: Yes, I noted this in a comment several minutes ago. No need to reiterate it as an answer as it's a typo, and if typos are the reason for the problems then the question should be closed as off-topic.